# Making a mobile version of forums

Tags: php, mobile

I am considering making a mobile version of a forum. I do not have database access. 
I am thinking i'll have to fetch the URL and sort out topics. Does anyone have other ideas or comments on how to achieve this?

Comment: So, meaning you only have access to the HTML?

Comment: Yes, i have no more access to it than anyone else

Comment: Ouch.  I guess first decide if you want to pre-fetch all the content (using a web crawler) and store it, or if you want to have the app transform the HTML format in real time..  Both could get tricky.

Comment: Is it that tricky? I imagined it would be pretty simple to sort out the topics content for instance, provided you have the ID of it

Comment: That stuff usually gets messy to maintain.  Things like IDs or HTML format changes as the site gets updated or new features are added.

Comment: Site updates are not going to happen :-) would this be the best way to do it? Eventually i am going to wrap it up in a smartphone app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to j_mcnally's answer, you should check out CSS media queries.  What you're looking to do sounds like you don't have much (or any) access to the code of the forum itself but you want to change the look.  You could definitely create a mobile version of the site like `mobile.yourname.com` but it's obviously preferred to have just `yourname.com` and have the stylesheet apply based off of screen size.  Technically you could sniff out the particular devices and apply a stylesheet to each them, but this is not preferrable seeing as you would have to create a style for every different possible screen size.

Long story short, you have a surprising amount of options: but use CSS media queries.  This practice is known as responsive design.  I'd highly recommend checking out [Ethan Marcotte's book](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design) (he's pretty much the guy who started the movement behind responsive CSS).  If you don't want to buy the book, I'd suggest [starting with his article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) which is a pretty good summary of the contents of the full book.  Either one is a huge help if you're looking to get into this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you awsome at CSS? The simplest soultion might be to create a proxy to the website, and just inject a stylesheet to make it render properly on mobile.

MediaQueries and CSS3 selectors and maybe even some JQuery/JS would be your friend here to do the transform easily.

Depending on your scripting language, (Ruby) you could leverage something like nokogiri to parse the XML/HTML to ensure your CSS file is injected in the proper page. and then return the modified DOM element as html. The tricky parts will be around managing multiple clinets authentication, but using a HTTP library that supports CookieJars would help alot. I for one would not use a Proxy like this and give my login info to a 3rd party. So your best bet would be to make it a read only app? if that is possible.